# Data Type Issue in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, data-conversion, sqldatatypes

I am trying to load data from a flat file into a MS SQL server table. The contents of the file are below.

```
Account Number,Prod Id Nr,COMP Cancel Revenue,YTD Revenue,PYE Revenue
001-0001-0,508,133,111,133
001-0001-0,701,28018,8485,16572
001-0001-0,702,28018,8485,16572
001-0001-0,851,13568,,
001-0001-0,951,13568,,
001-0001-0,1001,13568,,
```

I am using a Flat File Connection manager where Account Number is defined as Unicode Text, Prod Id Nr is defined as Numeric and other Revenue columns are defined as Decimal.

The SQL server table has corresponding columns where the Revenue columns are defined as "Numeric(18,0) NULL".

When I execute the SSIS package, it fails with the below error message.

```
 Name: OnError
 Computer: DBM01
 Operator: DOMAIN\QAUSER
 Source Name: Data Flow Task
 Source GUID: {c6f4977e-2bbf-4393-9be8-4e736bffa17f}
 Execution GUID: {C710ED31-1532-4EFF-B329-0C53753FD9F8}
 Message: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "PYE Revenue" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
```

Can someone help? Though the revenue columns are defined as Decimal in both source (flat file) and destination (SQL table), it is still failing. The revenue values in the file appear to be integer values, but we could get decimal values also. Also, the file can have blank values for the revenue field. Could this be the problem? Please note that the SQL column is defined to accept NULLs.

Comment: Best thing to do is pop some zeros into your file and see if it fixes it

Comment: Sure, will try that and see if that fixes the issue. So, what would be the solution if it fixes it. I assume csv file cannot nulls. So, blank values are empty strings and the requirements are to carry forward the nulls/blanks into the SQL server table. Should I use a derived column to check if the value is empty string and then convert to a null and see if that works?

Comment: Is the revenue field an "accounting" type coming from Excel by any chance? It might have other symbols (like $) or negatives that are not numeric/decimal type.

Comment: No. It is a .csv text file and it does not have the other symbols.